# Missing user_profile permission for page -- how can I get it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a WEB app that does the following:

1) User logs in using Facebook; I end up with an app-scoped ID (I use node's Passport for this, but that's kind of irrelevant)

2) User clicks on the checkbox plugin, after which I receive a page-scoped ID. The checkbox is there so that users accept Gigsnet's gig notifications.

3) At this point, my page (or my app, I am not 100% sure) HAS `user_messaging` but it's lacking `user_profile`. From the docs: "However, there may be other situations where only one (or neither) is granted, such as encountering the bot via a plugin or ad, or encountering a page shared by a friend using a bot." https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/permissions/

4) Since I lack that permission, my call to /ids_for_apps (documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching ) fails. The cause of this failure was confirmed by the FB developers. I need this call to look up the app-scoped user ID starting from the page-scoped user ID (so that my app knows how to message that specific logged in user)

The link provided by the developers is all about how to make a WebView from a mobile app. IF I managed to make that happen from my web app (I am not even sure that's possible), I would then be able to get Facebook to ask the user for the extra permission (which would be painful, but doable).

So... how on earth do I get that missing permission...?

- Will I need to somehow call the web view from my WEB app? If so, how?
- Is there an easier way to do this? For example granting that permission at login time?

This is the bug I opened with the Facebook developers, although I suspect they have much nastier and more urgent bugs to chase: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1560060124032512/

Answer (score 0):

The person needs to interact with your Messenger app. Here's a list of actions that will get you the user profile permission:

- The person starts the conversation via a welcome screen and tapped the "Get Started" button.
- The person starts the conversation by clicking a "Send to Messenger" button.
- The person starts the conversation by sending a message.
- The person starts the conversation by tapping a button.
- Your Messenger app uses the askPermission() function of the Messenger Extensions SDK in the webview to ask for the user_profile permission.

Comment: The last one: "Your Messenger app uses the askPermission() function of the Messenger Extensions SDK in the webview to ask for the user_profile permission." How would I include a "webview" in my web app?